# Gradle not creating a Tomcat deployable war

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, gradle, war

I'm running into an issue with building a war with Gradle 4.8.1.  Here is the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

archivesBaseName = 'sample'

//war {
//    archiveName = 'sample.war'
//    group = 'my.group'
//    version = '2.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
//}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "${nexusUrl}/content/groups/public" }
}

dependencies {

    // Spring
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    // Lombok
    compile "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.0"

    // Data
    compile ('org.postgresql:postgresql') {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-simple'
    }

    // Http
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5"
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "${nexusUrl}/content/groups/public/") {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/snapshots") {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }
            pom.version = '2.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
            pom.artifactId = 'sample'
            pom.groupId = 'my.group'
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried removing the 'maven' plugin, archivesBaseName, and the uploadArchive task while uncommenting the war task and I get the same result.  When using uploadArchive the war deploys to the nexus server fine and I get no errors.  When deploying the war to tomcat (in both instances) tomcat 7 and 8 throw no errors and I receive no logs from either catalina or the project, although archiveName inside the war task does not properly rename the war.  I have tried this on two other machines/tomcat instances with the same result.  When building this as a fat jar, or running this in IntelliJ, everything works as expected (including the logging).

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it is not initializing the servlet at all. Make sure to extend the SpringBootServletInitializer for WAR deployment.

- [Spring Boot Docs - Traditional Deployment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html)

Comment: Good call, I did forget to include the ServletInitializer but after adding it, the war still does not properly add the endpoints.  My one endpoint ends with php because it was originally written in that and I get file not found rather than bad request and nothing when hitting the index.html which is located in resources/static.

Comment: If you extract the contents of the war, does it have a proper directory structure? Also, do you see any logs in Tomcat now saying that any endpoints have been registered?

Comment: Sorry for not responding for so long, had a lot of other stuff I had to jump on.  I actually had to push some updates to this project as well and ran into issues when when checking out the gradle branch with modules in IntelliJ.  So I thought I'd start from scratch and rewrite in Kotlin and couldn't get it to upload anymore.  Looking at the documentation here,  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html, it looks like I need to implement a maven-like structure but with Spring Boot think that's pretty unnecessary.  Surprised maven is so much easier to work with

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. The issue is Spring application doesnt get initialized when the war is deployed on tomcat.

After a lot of struggle, I figured out that I needed to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` in my application. So my effective code looks like

```
    public class SyncApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SyncApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SyncApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Looks like this `SpringBootServletInitializer` directs war plugins generate bootstrapping code while building the war, and thus spring context is initialized while deploying the app.